# Is there a way to REQUIRE updates to Adobe and Java?

Tags: updates

I have problems with every member of my family not updating things. I'll come home and every single one of the computers will have the Windows update shield, the Adobe reader update icon, and the orange Java icon in the system tray. How do they not see it?? No matter how many times I tell them, they never update.

Is there any way that I can force the updates to run? Nowadays most updates (especially for reader and Java) don't even require a restart! Why can't they just run in the background automatically?

How do I solve this problem??

Answer (score 3):

For Windows and Reader you can configure the preferences so that updates are installed automatically. Java still requires some action however. There's a good chance they aren't using Java except rarely, so just uninstall it - it will be back if it's needed and in the meantime it's one less security hole. And since they have probably been cancelling the virus scans too, every bit helps...

Alternatively you can do the updates yourself with LogMeIn or Teamviewer.

Personally, I gave up and put them all on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

A guide entitled [Use Ninite and Task Scheduler to Keep Relatives' Computers Up to Date](http://lifehacker.com/5702096/use-ninite-and-task-scheduler-to-keep-relatives-computers-up-to-date) might be worth a read.